# Programa simples para calculo de médias escolares em C com vetor

Tags: c, algoritmo, programação-estruturada

Olá, estou tentando fazer funcionar um pequeno programa que eu gostaria que lesse uma determinada média, armazenasse 4 notas do aluno X, calculasse a média dessas notas e comparasse com a nota  média  minima exigida pela  instituicao.

Entretanto, estou com problemas, pois ao mostrar a média do aluno (e a soma de suas notas) obtenho um número muito grande, que não faz sentido algum. Também estou com problemas para fazer a pontuação aparecer corretamente no cmd. Estou usando o compilador gcc, obtido através do MinGW.Segue o código.

Obs:Estão marcando essa pergunta como já respondida, porém a resposta exigente não sana minhas dúvida, pois não estou lidando com funções e meu programa difere em muitos pontos da pergunta já existente, como por exemplo, na utilização de vetor e no uso da bibilioteca locale.h.
 `

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");


    double medias[3];
    double somaNotas;
    double media;
    double mediaInstituicao;

printf("\nPor favor digite a nota media da instituicao em questão");
scanf("%d", mediaInstituicao);

    for (int i = 0; i<=3; i++){
      int n;
      n = i+1;
        printf("\nPor favor, digite a %i º nota do aluno: \n",(i+1));
        scanf("%d",&medias[i]);
        somaNotas += medias[i];

    }

    printf("\nA soma das notas é igual À: %.2d",somaNotas);

    media = (somaNotas/4);


   printf("A média À: %.2d",media);

    if(media >= mediaInstituicao){

        printf("\nO aluno foi aprovado, não haverá necessidade de fazer a segunda prova pois sua m�dia foi %.2d");



    } else{
        printf("\nO aluno foi reprovado, ele terá de fazer a 5º prova, pois suma média foi somente %2.d", media);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Poste o código completo, com os `#includes`

Comment: Seus dados são do tipo `double` mas você está tentando ler e escrever como se fossem `int`, ex:  `double media;` ... `scanf("%d",&medias[i]);`. Ajuste os formatos de escrita e leitura de seus `printf` e `scanf` de `%d`(`int`) para `%lf`(`double`).